# The collapse navbar can't open on CodePen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

here is my code:

https://codepen.io/qtoq126/pen/gevXza

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

切换导航
        
        
        
      
      QIN

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I don't know why the code can run correctly on other IDEs.

Can anybody solve my problem?

thank you all guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add jQuery and Bootstrap3 in Settings / Javascript section

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Jquery and the Bootstrap Javascript file.

In Codepen, select Settings > Javascript.

Then use the quick-add dropdowns to add Jquery THEN Bootstrap 3. Jquery needs to be added before the Bootstrap Javascript file.

Comment: "Jquery needs to be added before the Bootstrap Javascript file" this is the key point , thx very much